# What are graph datastores better at doing than other datastores and why?

Tags: data, relational-database, graph-databases

Where previously there was only relational databases, the data store world is now rife with options like Key-Value, Document, and Graph datastores. Unfortunately, every datastore likes to show how it can be used for *anything*, but none of them really help people figure out when to use one model over another.

So, the question is: **What "things" are graph datastores better at than relational datastores?** (ie. faster, simpler, more flexible, more powerful) **What makes them better at doing those things?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highly connected graphs are not easy to model or query using relational databases.

Think about social graphs - Bob is a friend to Alice, Alice is a friend to Carol.

How many friends of friends does Bob have?

Modelling and querying this kind of data is what graph datastores are good at.

Another example - think about Dr Who episodes and a corpus of data about all the actors, characters and sets used in them. In a graph datastore you could query all the episodes an actor was in a specific set with a specific character - this is not easy to model or query in relational database.

Comment: So, answering the the n-steps-away sorts of questions? Or, to put it another way, answering questions that rely on transitivity?

Comment: @cdeszaq - Its about traversing and querying relationships between objects as well as the objects themselves.

Comment: With the edit: Also multi-relational data? Commonly called ternary relationships, where you need to connect n different entities so a RDBMS "associative table" gets unwieldy as the number of entities to connect gets larger?

Comment: @cdeszaq - Definitely multi-relational data.

Comment: @cdeszaq - Check out http://neo4j.org/

Comment: From the comment: The graph datastores surface the relationship-as-data aspect that relational models struggle with

Comment: This isn't at the right level to be a good "why is this different?" paper, but this might give youa  taste: http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/current/agraph-introduction.html